# Set 48000 Hz by microphone

Tags: sound, microphone

On Windows I can set the input Hz to 48000. With 41000 Hz my microphon makes annoying sounds. With 48000 Hz this is solved in Windows. So how can I set the frequency in Ubuntu globally for all application, especially Skype?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may find some help at http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc - because the 'frequency' you want to change is technically called **sample rate**.

Comment: I didn't know sample rate at the moment I wrote this post. Was forgotten ^^ thanks for the link

Comment: This can't help. It does not work for microphone sample rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default sample rate is defined in the pulseaudio `daemon.conf` located in `/etc/pulse`, or in case you need user-defined settings in `~/.pulse`. Uncomment and edit the follwing line there

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

Changes take effect after a restart of the Pulseaudio server (issue `pulseaudio -k` in a terminal or log out and back in).